# How to obtain Windows Notification Service?

Tags: c#, push-notification, uwp, wns

I am developing a Windows 10 UWP application using c#, and I need to send push notifications. When I searched for it, learned that I need a Windows Notification Service, but I could not understand how can I have it. Can you explain or suggest me any resource about it.

Thans in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you: 
[Windows Push Notification Services (WNS) overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187203.aspx)

[Quickstart: Sending a push notification (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868252.aspx)